# Run my own application master on a specific node in a YARN cluster

Tags: hadoop, containers, hadoop-yarn

First of all, I'm using Hadoop-2.6.0. I want to launch my own app master on a specific node in a YARN cluster in order to open a server on a predetermined IP address and port. To that end, I wrote a driver program in which I created a **ResourceRequest** object and called **setResourceName** method to set a hostname, and attached it to a **ApplicationSubmissionContext** object by calling **setAMContainerResourceRequest** method.

I tried several times but couldn't launch the app master on a specific node. After searching code, I found that **RMAppAttemptImpl** invalidates what I've set in **ResourceRequest** as follows:

```
    // Currently, following fields are all hard code,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    // TODO: change these fields when we want to support                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    // priority/resource-name/relax-locality specification for AM containers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    // allocation.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    appAttempt.amReq.setNumContainers(1);
    appAttempt.amReq.setPriority(AM_CONTAINER_PRIORITY);
    appAttempt.amReq.setResourceName(ResourceRequest.ANY);
    appAttempt.amReq.setRelaxLocality(true);
```

Is there another way to launch a container for an application master on a specific node in Hadoop-2.6.0?

Answer (score 2):

[ApplicationSubmissionContext](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ApplicationSubmissionContext.html#setAMContainerResourceRequest(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.ResourceRequest)) provides a function [setAMContainerResourceRequest](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ApplicationSubmissionContext.html#setAMContainerResourceRequest%28org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.ResourceRequest%29) where you can pass a [ResourceRequest](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ResourceRequest.html) object, In ResourceRequest object you can set "false" the RelaxLocality flag,  which tells the ResourceManager if the application wants locality to be loose (i.e. allows fall-through to rack or any) or strict (i.e. specify hard constraint on resource allocation). Then set the hostname using [setResourceName](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ResourceRequest.html#setResourceName%28java.lang.String%29). I hope it helps!

Comment: That is what I did and does not work because RMAppAttempt changes resource name to ResourceRequest.ANY and set whether to relax locality to true as in the above code (see the code section in the original question). RMAppAttempt did that before asking RM to allocate a container to launch AM.