# Executors on CORE node in EMR cluster

Tags: hadoop-yarn, emr

In the EMR cluster I have 1 MASTER, 1 CORE and 4 TASK nodes. It seems the YARN is creating CPU bound SPARK executors not only on TASK nodes, but also on CORE node. Is there any option to prevent it (like 'yarn.app.mapreduce.am.labels' does to instruct YARN to create APP MANAGER only on MASTER or CORE).

Comment: Why CORE node is part of the cluster if you don't want any executors on it?

Comment: To have only AM on it. I want to run many AM and single master is not enough to do it. I don't want to have executors on CORE to not lock resources for AMs.

Comment: AM runs inside a container. At most, you can specify which node to run your AMs on. These refs should help you: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.2/bk_yarn_resource_mgt/content/configuring_node_labels.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302659/run-my-own-application-master-on-a-specific-node-in-a-yarn-cluster

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. It almost worked, but some issues emerged like here: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/11129. It is supposed to be fixed in YARN 2.8.0. So far Amazon installs 2.7.3. I will wait for Amazon's update and test it again.

Comment: Yr wc. I have added it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AM runs inside a container. At most, you can specify which node to run your AMs on.

These refs should help you:

- https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.2/bk_yarn_resource_mgt/content/configuring_node_labels.html
- [Run my own application master on a specific node in a YARN cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302659/run-my-own-application-master-on-a-specific-node-in-a-yarn-cluster)

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent launching executor container on core nodes with these two approaches as mentioned below:

- In EMR core node is having yarn node label 'CORE' as Non-exclusive partition. Because core node is non-exclusive partition another container can be launched there. To prevent launching executor container on core node you can make it 'exclusive' partition.

  There are two kinds of node partitions:
    Exclusive: containers will be allocated to nodes with exactly match node partition. (e.g. asking partition=“x” will be allocated to node with partition=“x”, asking DEFAULT partition will be allocated to DEFAULT partition nodes).
    Non-exclusive: if a partition is non-exclusive, it shares idle resource to container requesting DEFAULT partition.
  source : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeLabel.html
  You can also find how to add or modify node labels here.
- Another approach to handle it is to assign yarn node label to all your task nodes as 'TASK' and use below configuration in spark submit command.

```
        spark.yarn.am.nodeLabelExpression='CORE'
        spark.yarn.executor.nodeLabelExpression='TASK'
```